# Having problems getting info back from the mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I had this working on another website but amending this is causing me problems and I can't see where it thinks there are extra parameters.

I'll add Javascript later but I need to be able to select from a Dropdown menu and print the corresponding info from the database. My PHP code is as follows:

```
 include('definitions.php');

 $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

 echo "These are the matches for the search";
 echo "<br>";

 $query="SELECT name,email,town,location,gmapslink FROM users WHERE `town` = '?'";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_POST['select1']);
 var_dump($_POST);

 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

 /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col2, $col3, $col5, $col8, $col9);

 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
   {
    printf("Name:%s\t Email:%s\t Town:%s\t Location:%s\t Google Maps Link:%s\t", $col2,    $col3, $col5, $col8, $col9);
   echo "<br>";

   }

    /* close statement */
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);


 /* close connection */
 mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Reply I get back from the website is as follows.
These are the matches for the search:

PHP Error Message:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/a5839517/public_html/search.php on line 18

Free Web Hosting:

> array(3) { ["county"]=> string(15) "Outside Ireland" ["select1"]=> string(12) "Ballincollig" ["select"]=> NULL }

Running the SQL code on the database works fine, but in this case to get it working I had to add quotes around `town` and `?`.

Any ideas what my issue is as parameters seem to be correct.

Added edit from original file that calls the php above:

```
 <form action="search.php" method="post">
 County <select name="county">
 <option>   Outside Ireland </option>
 <option>   Antrim  </option>
 <option>   Armagh  </option>

 </select>
 <br>
 Name of Book
 <?php
 mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS) or die("Connection Failed");
 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)or die("Connection Failed");
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT town FROM users";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 ?>
 <select name="select1">
 <?php
 while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $line['town'];?>"> <?php echo $line['town'];?> </option> 
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 </select>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Code is corrected above to have select1 statement and column name in backticks.

Comment: `$_POST["select"]` is null. Do you mean to be using `$_POST["select1"]` (which does look like a town name)?

Comment: +1 for using `mysqli_`.. quite a rarity around here.

Comment: Don't quote your prepared statement placeholders: `?`, not `'?'`

Comment: @andrewsi I have 2 drop down menus and my idea is that eventually I will have Javascript to filter the second dropdown but I am only selecting "Ballincollig" ["select"]=> NULL for the time being.

Comment: @FrancisAvila I can't get any results if I run the SQL directly on the database without the single quotes

Comment: @daithi_dearg - I think the issue is that you're passing `NULL` as the bound parameter. Could you try altering the SQL so that it's got backticks around town, no quotes around the `?` and pass the string `Ballincollig` as the last parameter for `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` ?

Comment: @andrewsi You can't pass a string to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. It uses references, so you have to give a variable.

Comment: Why are you binding the parameter to `$_POST['select']`? Shouldn't it be `$_POST['town']`?

Comment: @andrewsi Changed lines as follows: $query="SELECT name,email,town,location,gmapslink FROM users WHERE `town` = 'Ballincollig'";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", 'Ballincollig');  Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /home/a5839517/public_html/search1.php on line 18  Have I misinterpreted what you were suggesting?

Comment: @Barmar I had this working before and I used the select variable

Comment: I don't see an input named `select` in your HTML, where is that coming from? I see `select1`, maybe that's what you should be using.

Comment: @andrewsi Sorry I didn't catch your point earlier but the select1 was my problem. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try it, instead of quotes around town, use backticks around town instead.

Comment: Your answer is more suited as a comment/suggestion. ;)

Comment: @connorgurney Tried following directly on database "SELECT name,email,town,location,gmapslink FROM users WHERE `town` = `Ballincollig`" where Ballincollig is an entry in the database and it fails with message #1054 - Unknown column 'Ballincollig' in 'where clause'. Also tried without backticks for Ballincollig and same thing. This is also the error I was seeing before adding single quotes.

Comment: @daithi_dearg - you need to quote column names with backticks; and values with single quotes. If you're using a bound parameter, you need neither, as it's taken care of for you by the driver.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as stated by several people in the comments, that you're passing `null` to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`.

The `var_dump` does indeed clearly show that you should be using the value of `$_POST['select1']`. To verify, perhaps instead of dumping the contents of the `$_POST` array, printing/echoing the return value of `mysqli_stmt_error()` on line 19 *could* prove very useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put quotes around the ? and town in your statement:

```
$query="SELECT name,email,town,location,gmapslink FROM users WHERE 'town' = '?'";
```

It should be

```
$query="SELECT name,email,town,location,gmapslink FROM users WHERE town = ?";
```

town is a column name and shouldn't be quoted; ? is a special character that gets substituted by the mysql interface.

Comment: ok I took out the single quotes and I now get result "These are the matches for the search
array(3) { ["county"]=> string(4) "Cork" ["select1"]=> string(12) "Ballincollig" ["select"]=> &NULL }". It appears to me that I need my code to have both variables but from my perspective I only need to query the second statement or am I mistaking it.

Comment: You need to remove the quote around `town`, did you?